# Decoding TX input (contract isn't verified at BSCscan and ABI is unknown)

Tags: web3js, web3.py, ethers.js, abi, bsc

I tied to decode transaction's input for the specific contract
Contract source code is unknown and ABI is unknown too. At BSCscan contract isn't verified and built-in decompiling returns a mess

Contract address (BSC) - **0x22726abde7ad5496f7cdb12c1356772e847e6996**

example tx hash: **0x51a0035fd27270ed1966731a575aa8161b37fac20cb5cdfdd05cf835e15cd610**

So I want to find a way to see the tx data as it displayed in BSCscan.
(https://bscscan.com/tx/0x51a0035fd27270ed1966731a575aa8161b37fac20cb5cdfdd05cf835e15cd610)

Comment: Without ABI / source code, its not possible to decode the input

Comment: If it is impossible - how BSCscan itself decode input and return all tx data in human-readable format?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it's not possible to decode the input data without the ABI. Your ABI specified what data and data type in encoded in the function parameters. That said, you might have seen etherscan/bscscan with decoded input parameters. Thanks to sources like https://www.4byte.directory/, we have a list of known function signatures and their parameter types. These block explorers likely use something similar to decode known functions. So if the function call you are trying to decode is known in the signature database, you  can technically decode it.  For example, lets say the input data is `0x2e1a7d4d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038d7ea4c680000`.

In that, the first 4 bytes are the function signature - `0x2e1a7d4`. The remaining are input parameters.

We could then lookup in https://www.4byte.directory/ for the signature ([link](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x2e1a7d4d)). It says the function is `withdraw(uint256)`.

Now that we have the function definition, we can easily decode the input. You can do it via libraries like web3 or ethers, or some web [tools](https://www.moesif.com/solidity-abi-hex-decoder/decode) to do the same. In this case, the input is `0x38d7ea4c680000` which is the hex for `16000000000000000`. So the function call was `withdraw(16000000000000000)`.

But like said, this worked only because the function signature of `withdraw(256)` was known. If it's a new function signature that is not previously known, it's impossible to decode the input. You can read more about how input is encoded [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/abi-spec.html).